# Accelerometr in Lenovo Thinkpad E330

Tags: hard-drive, lenovo, thinkpad

How can I enable active HDD protection on Lenovo TP Edge 13.
 Ubuntu 13.10 hdapsd says that there is no accelerometer, but in windows it worked! I tried to shake a laptop while it was reading hdd, but hdd didn't parked